# Heroku assets precompile error, despite compiling assets locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

I am currently first time deploying my app to Heroku, and am encountering the precompile error.  When I execute the command `git push heroku master`, I get:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

After a bit of searching, I encountered both Heroku's own [troubleshooting guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#troubleshooting) on precompile error, as well as this [post](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/) on precompile errors and Rails 3.2, and following their directions, did the following:

1. Added `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to my `application.rb` file
2. Made a new heroku app using `heroku create` just to be safe
3. Per the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

I thought that since I am doing the compiling *locally*, when pushing to Heroku it would just skip the compilation part based on detecting a manifest.yml file.  However, even when I do so, when running `git push heroku master`, it will still run `rake assets:precompile` and generate the same error as seen above.

Thanks in advance for you help!

**Addendum**

In my .gitignore, I have the following:

```
# Ignore bundler config
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I would assume that it should work.

Can you confirm that you have committed and merged all changes into master? i.e. `git status`

Comment: specifically make sure `public/assets` is in `git ls-files` and you're not ignoring that directory in `.gitignore`.

Comment: @ ctshryock I just checked via `git ls-files`, and see that public/assets indeed show up.  I think you may be onto something.  I also posted what is in my `.gitignore` file in my root directory in the body of the question.

Comment: @crftr - this was the case (and solved the problem!).  I made sure everything was added and it now works.  However, now its directing me straight to the default rails "Welcome to Rails" page.. but I routed my root directory to somewhere else.

Comment: @daspianist - Excellent!  The welcome to rails page is likely due to having the default public/index.html page.  Delete the file and redeploy to heroku.